# Do I need a private docker registry?

Tags: docker, coreos

I've recently discovered docker.  It looks very useful for us.

But what I don't understand is the role of the registry beyond getting initial docker images.  We'll likely be starting with some images based on those from docker.io, but will be customizing those and adding some private closed source software.

What concerns me is if the images were large enough then could I run out of space on my / drive.

Can /var/lib/docker just be a mount to a shared file system like cephfs or nfs?

I'm also interested in using CoreOS in a PXE or iPXE configuration.  It appears that in that scenario / is mounted as tmpfs up to 50% RAM which is needlessly wasteful for pulling images that could be available on a shared file system.  However I've read comments that for some reason /var/lib/docker needs to be on btrfs.  Is this true? why?

---

Ok I've found an answer to my last question.  CoreOS requires /var/lib/docker to be mounted on btrfs because it uses the btrfs backend.  This backend uses btrfs snapshots to implement the layers docker uses to represent it's image.

Which helps with my second question.  Can /var/lib/docker just be a mount to a shared file system.  By the looks of it, no. Not unless the super slow vfs backend is used.

Comment: oops, I was meant to put this question onto serverfault.  If someone could migrate it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy and cheap to [store your registry in S3](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry).

I would recommend against mounting /var/lib/docker on nfs.  If someone hammers the nfs, all your services will essentially stop working, since the file systems of the containers live there.

Comment: Why would I store it in S3 when I have Terabytes of fast local storage in cephfs or rbd available for free?  Besides that, you're not answering the question(s)

Comment: And yeah I'm aware that the docker registry code has a ceph-s3 backend available.  I'm just wondering why is all this needed, can't I just do a mount rather than duplicate the data.

Comment: I don't think of the registry as duplicated, in the same way I don't think of my repos on github as duplicated.  It is a central place where all of your many machines will get their services.